# How to get periodic status updates from the thermal printer using escpos commands in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I am planning to get periodic status updates from the thermal printer in android kotlin. The main reason for this is that when the printing request is initiated and if the printer job fails in the middle (eg: due to insufficient paper), and when a new paper roll is inserted it starts to print the receipt again which in my case I need to stop that from happening.

These are some things I brainstormed and tried to find solutions,

1. Clear the buffer: Buffer could be cleared with the ESCPOS commands but how to guarantee whether there is a printing job queued in the printer. For example even if I clear the buffer after certain time my printing job is initiated and still it won't do anything unless when a new paper is inserted it starts printing again. It may means that i am trying to clear the buffer even before the printing job is paused. So if it is then we cannot guarantee a certain interval where the printer would potentially pause the printing job. **NO SOLUTION**
2. Periodic updates: I could run a while loop for certain time intervals and check the status but it adds extra overload to the application and the printer, which I don't want to. **NOT A SOLUTION**
3. Is there an ESCPOS command which sends periodic updates: Unfortunately didn't find any. Even if there is a command how to use it if I am using a seperate library for initiating the printing request? **QUESTION AND NO SOLUTION**

So are there any suggestions and approaches which I could use to solve this issue? What i simply need is to stop the printer from resuming its printing job when it's failed for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to mention how the printer is connected to Android, network (Wifi?), USB, Bluetooth, serial, ...

Comment: It can be either way @Robert. What I basically implemented as of now is ethernet and usb, but bluetooth and wifi will be implemented later